# Open a terminal from any directory using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to be able to open a terminal using a keyboard shortcut from any directory I am currently in. Software based approaches are not an option as I do not have the ability to install software on this PC. It is an office and I don't have admin rights.

The second answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632569/quicker-way-to-open-an-ubuntu-terminal-in-a-particular-directory) specifies how to setup a keyboard shortcut to do open a terminal, however it turns out that it always just opens the terminal in the home directory so it is not what I am looking for.

So is there a way to open a terminal from any directory using only a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: This is highly dependant on the window manager and file manager used. Can you specify which distro/WM/file manager you are using?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Dolphin file manager, there's a build in shortcut `Shift + F4`  that does exactly this.

Comment: This opens a terminal in the directory in which *Nautilus* is, not where the current terminal is.

Comment: Isn't that what he's asking?

Comment: Quote: *from any directory I am currently in*. I understood that to be any directory in the terminal, not in Nautilus.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Unlike  @LuboKanev, I understood the OP to mean: *a shortcut to open a new terminal in the present working directory I find myself in, in the currently active terminal*, not in the file manager (BTW, in KDE there is the same trick pointed out in the other answer: in Doplhin, you use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>; I believe any decent file manager will provide such a key).

The script below is a tad complex for this reason: in the current active window you may have a currently running task (say, you are watching a movie via *vlc*), so you do not have the prompt available; how do you then retrieve your *PWD* without waiting for the completion of the task, *i.e.* without waiting for the movie to finish? The script solves exactly this problem.

---

The following script first identifies the current active window, then identifies the process running into it (it will be something like `konsole`, or `xterm`, or ..., if it is a terminal), then finds the children processes of `konsole/xterm/...`, and, for every child process which is a `bash` shell, it locates its current working directory and opens a `konsole` window in the given current directory. It does so for **all** bash shells found open, not just the first one.

```
#!/bin/bash

ACT_WIN=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
MY_PPID=$(xprop -id $ACT_WIN _NET_WM_PID | awk '{print $3}')

for i in $(pgrep -P $MY_PPID); do
      ps -o cmd -p "$i" | grep bash > /dev/null
      if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
         MYPWD=$(readlink -e /proc/$i/cwd)
         konsole --workdir $MYPWD 2>/dev/null & disown
      fi
done
```

**Careful**, there is no error checking in the above....

The good thing about this script is that, if the current active window is not a terminal, hence it has spawn no *bash* shells, nothing will happen. You may then click with the mouse on your terminal, which becomes the current active directory, and resend the shortcut: you will then get your terminal, and the proper directory.

After making this script executable, you can associate it to a keyboard shortcut; this depends on DM. For KDE, go to `System Settings ->  Shortcuts and Gestures ->  Custom Shortcuts -> Edit (in the lower left corner) -> New -> Global -Shortcut -> Command/URL`. Under `New Action`, choose `Comment` to explain what you are doing, then the `trigger` (the command, something like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>), and then, under action, enter the absolute path to the executable script above.